# Dynamically creating dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have a huge dataset that I want to split in several smallers ones, based on the string values of the first column.

By now, I have deleted all the information that I don't want in the final dataframes and to create dynamically using a dictionary of dataframes, to no avail, and to create the split.

For the dictionary of dataframes, I tried:

```
dict = {}
number_of_df= 0

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df[i:] != df[i-1]:
        number_of_df += 1

for i in range(len(number_of_df)):
    d['t' + str(i)] = df.shift(i).add_suffix('_t' + str(i))
```

And for copying the values of the rows till the first value in the row differ from the preceeding one:

```
for key in dict:
    while df[i:] == df[i-1:]:
        df[key].append= df2.loc[df1.index[i]] = df1.iloc[i]

    df[key].to_csv('file'+str(key)+'.csv', index=False)
```

I expected it to create several CSVs with each file named with the order in which it was created. I have several errors, first it says Key error: -1 while creating the dictionary and only creates an empty one, and when slicing doesn't return no error but doesn't write anything to the dictionary either. I also think that I may be pointing wrong to which rows and values I want to change in the dictionary.

Thanks in advance an sorry for my english, not mothertongue and also a complete n00b.

Comment: `based on the string values of the first column`: where do you filter by the first column in your code? Also, *never* (even in an example) use a built-in such as `dict` for a variable name.

Comment: I supposed I was filtering in the 3 line of the second chunk. The rows hace the same value for like 900 instances. I wanted to copy rows in the dataframe till the values did not match. Sorry for the dict thing, had no idea.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a dictionary `d` where the keys are the *unique strings* in your first column and the values are the dataframes filtered for the respective strings?

Comment: I was thinking more like a dictionary of dataframes (following an advice I read in another post) for dynamically creating dataframes. I'm open to suggestions. The problem I was aiming to solve was to split this large CSV into smallers one, each smaller one containing the data associated to a repeating key in the first column.

Comment: OK, a dictionary is optional and not actually necessary, see my solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to split in several smallers ones, based on the string values
>   of the first column.

This is easier than you think. Just use `groupby` with your first column, then use `dict` + `tuple` to construct your dictionary. You can select the first column via indexing `df.columns`.

```
dct = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.columns[0])))
```

If you *only* need to export each dataframe to a CSV file, you don't need the extra expense of a dictionary. Just iterate the `groupby` object directly:

```
for key, df_slice in df.groupby(df.columns[0]):
    df_slice.to_csv(f'file_{key}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Wow, 2 lines? It worked, I'm really impressed. So much to learn. Thank you!

Comment: @AaronGonzález, No problem, if this helped don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer (tick on left).